# Why does 1 != 1 return true?

Tags: java, redis, integer, int

```
if (responseEntity.getBody().getMeta().getCode() != ApiExceptionEnum.SUCCESS.code()) {
    return null;
}
```

code like this,

```
responseEntity.getBody().getMeta().getCode() -> Integer  1
ApiExceptionEnum.SUCCESS.code() -> Integer 1
```

sometimes it will return null !!

why ?

the response is from redis

Comment: use `equals` to compare objects not `==` or `!=`

Comment: For the same reason that `new Integer(1) == Integer.valueOf(1)` is `false`.

Comment: thank you , finally i use Integer.intValue ,  but  why when Integer = 1, such code ,` Integer != Integer` return true ?

Comment: in java when Integer little then 128   1= 1 return true , when Interger bigger then 128 1= 1 return false ,but I got the situation 1 != 1 return true

Answer (score 0):

In this case `==` or `!=` checks whether compared objects are pointing to the same place in memory. To compare values stored in compared objects, use `.equals()` method inherited by all Java objects from `Object` class.

Comment: when the Interger is 1 , why it doesn't aotuunboxing?

Comment: @JasonYu Because equals() method is inherited by objects, primitive types are not considered as objects in Java and they aren't inheriting anything. If you call this method it means that you want to compare objects, not primitive types